# Springboot with Maven running a react with webpack

Tags: maven, heroku, spring-boot

So, I have a project with springboot that includes a maven pom file. In my pom.xml i included a front end plugin to run a npm command to start my react.js project, that uses a webpack. So when I try to deploy this app on Heroku deploy never ends, because maven run a npm run start and deploy never finishes.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>web</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>

              <execution>
                <id>install node and npm</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <nodeVersion>v4.2.1</nodeVersion>
                  <npmVersion>3.5.3</npmVersion>
                </configuration>
              </execution>

              <execution>
                <id>npm install</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <arguments>install</arguments>
                </configuration>
              </execution>

              <execution>
                <id>npm run build</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>npm</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <arguments>run start</arguments>
                </configuration>
              </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I removed a npm run build step deploy runs good, but frontend doesn't start.

How can I fix this?

My full code is: https://github.com/ricardocunha/springboot-jwt-reactjs/

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest something.

I think you are facing this problem because you are trying `run start` argument and thus the code never builds up. Probably you can try again by replacing `run start` with `run build`.